# Duplicate classes in same jars of different versions - Android

Tags: java, android, gradle

I was trying to integrate iText in my Android Studio project when the sync successfully completed.
Then I wrote some code and tried to build and test it when it gave an error (A huge one) that duplicate classes were found in same jars of different versions. (I have removed some because there were a lot)

```
Duplicate class com.keypoint.PngEncoder found in modules jcommon-1.0.15.jar (jfree:jcommon:1.0.15) and jcommon-1.0.17.jar (org.jfree:jcommon:1.0.17)
Duplicate class org.jfree.JCommon found in modules jcommon-1.0.15.jar (jfree:jcommon:1.0.15) and jcommon-1.0.17.jar (org.jfree:jcommon:1.0.17)
Duplicate class org.jfree.JCommonInfo found in modules jcommon-1.0.15.jar (jfree:jcommon:1.0.15) and jcommon-1.0.17.jar (org.jfree:jcommon:1.0.17)
Duplicate class org.jfree.base.AbstractBoot found in modules jcommon-1.0.15.jar (jfree:jcommon:1.0.15) and jcommon-1.0.17.jar (org.jfree:jcommon:1.0.17)
Duplicate class org.jfree.base.BaseBoot found in modules jcommon-1.0.15.jar (jfree:jcommon:1.0.15) and jcommon-1.0.17.jar (org.jfree:jcommon:1.0.17)
Duplicate class org.jfree.base.BasicProjectInfo found in modules jcommon-1.0.15.jar (jfree:jcommon:1.0.15) and jcommon-1.0.17.jar (org.jfree:jcommon:1.0.17)
...
Duplicate class org.jfree.base.BasicProjectInfo$OptionalLibraryHolder found in modules jcommon-1.0.15.jar (jfree:jcommon:1.0.15) and jcommon-1.0.17.jar (org.jfree:jcommon:1.0.17)
Duplicate class org.jfree.base.BootableProjectInfo found in modules jcommon-1.0.15.jar (jfree:jcommon:1.0.15) and jcommon-1.0.17.jar (org.jfree:jcommon:1.0.17)
jcommon-1.0.17.jar (org.jfree:jcommon:1.0.17)
Duplicate class org.jfree.util.WaitingImageObserver found in modules jcommon-1.0.15.jar (jfree:jcommon:1.0.15) and jcommon-1.0.17.jar (org.jfree:jcommon:1.0.17)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

From this I Understand that the different versions of the same jar caused this issue. So I tried to remove the one with lower version (jcommon-1.0.15 and 1 more ) but when i synced the project with gradle, it again downloaded them and if i ran it offline it said that dependencies couldn't be resolved. Similar is the case with the jars of higher version.

**Update:**
Here are my `build.gradle` files as requested:
Project level:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nalin.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation project(path: ':libraries:OpenCV')
    implementation 'itext:itext:4.2.1'
}
```

I Also have included OpenCV so here is the gradle file for OpenCV:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 2480
        versionName "2.4.8"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show `build.gradle`

Comment: also, try to avoid using different versions of the same library

Comment: I have given my gradle files @IntelliJAmiya .

Comment: @Stultuske I actually do not even know from where the two versions came. 1 came as a dependency to iText that i know about but I don't know from where the other version came.

Comment: Execute `./gradlew app:dependencies` and check which ones you need to exclude so they are not repeated. Check [the gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies) about this.

Comment: have you tried getting a dependency tree?

Comment: you have properly two same/similar dependencies in your dependency graph: jfree:jcommon:1.0.15 and org.jfree:jcommon:1.0.17. Please use dependency graph to figure out, where they come from. After that you have to decide to avoid one of them by using excluding syntax, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html for more information how to exclude some libs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the guys in the comments, I could solve the problem quite easily.
What i did was ran `gradlew app:dependencies` and it gave me a dependency tree.

From that tree i could make out which parts of the library required which transitive dependencies and i excluded the jcommon library of the lower version which did not have any other dependencies using:
`exclude group: 'jfree', module: 'jcommon'`