# Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.BinaryDecoder found in modules jetified-commons-codec-1.15 (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15)

Tags: java, android, google-translation-api

I am getting below error after adding the Google cloud translation API in my project. I have tried many solutions but nothing is working as expected. Below is the runtime error occuring.

```
Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.BinaryEncoder found in modules jetified-JetEncryptor_v19-runtime (JetEncryptor_v19.aar) and jetified-commons-codec-1.15 (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15)
Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.CharEncoding found in modules jetified-JetEncryptor_v19-runtime (JetEncryptor_v19.aar) and jetified-commons-codec-1.15 (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

It is showing error for 92 classes that are in package org.apache.commons.codec of commons-codec. (cannot post whole thing)

I have tried using below snippet in build.gradle file.

configurations {
all*.exclude group: 'commons-codec', module: 'commons-codec'
}

But it is throwing below excepion.

**`Unable to load class 'org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils'.`**

I have used Gradle dependencies from Cloud API documentation.

If I remove cloud-translation api dependencies, the code works fine, but if I add it again same error occurs at runtime. My code already have a library which contains above listed classes and I cannot remove that library.

Please help me resolve the same as I have found no satisfactory solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had same problem with two different libs ... I think you cant use them simultaneously

Comment: Is there any way to ignore one of the two library's classes ? I have tried so many solutions but nothing worked. Or is there any way to use Google cloud translation API without dependencies ?

Comment: Have you search for other question like: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64180196/duplicate-classes-in-gradle-build-in-android-studio-application) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63450574/duplicate-classes-in-same-jars-of-different-versions-android)?

Comment: Yes.. I tried all those but it didnt worked.

Comment: Can you add the link to "Gradle dependencies from Cloud API documentation"? I cannot find this....

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup#client_libraries